# How do I partially break a clipping mask border?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, workflow, smartobject

I’m looking for a non-destructive way of allowing an image to be partially "clipped" by a clipping mask, like so:

[image]

I view the above image as having three parts…

- a **Person** (top layer; being clipped)
- a **Pattern** (background layer; being clipped)
- a **Shape** (bottom layer; does the clipping)

The **Person** and **Pattern** represent the crux of the matter, since the pattern should be clipped entirely, whereas the person is only partially clipped.

### Here’s an example of how I achieved this (in an undesired manner):

#### #1

Here is my **Shape**, accompanied by the **Pattern** and **Person** that will eventually be "clipped" by said Circle:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/PeRvLp5.png]

*(This is where my process becomes convoluted)*

#### #2

First, I create a Duplicate Layer of my **Person** and horizontally align this layer with my **Shape**. Like so:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/fL28z7V.png]

#### #3

Next, I use the magic wand to select my **Circle**.

#### #4

After which, I use the Magnetic lasso tool to add the top of my duplicate **Person** to the same selection.

#### #5

I then use this selection to create a Layer Mask for my **Person**.

#### #6

Finally, I merge these two layers into one shape. Here is what I have thus far:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/fjMMDUO.png]

*(From here on it becomes simple)*

#### #7

I used my (now rasterized) shape to as a clipping mask for **Pattern**…

[image: http://i.imgur.com/dLVYqXz.png]

#### #8

and finally my original **Person**…

[image: http://i.imgur.com/dj1P2Vi.png]

*(Fin)*

Is there straightforward way to allowing my **Person** to "escape" my clipping mask and move around freely without Steps #2 through #6, which is limiting due to obvious disadvantages.

For example: If I decided I wanted to offset my **Person**, after my "clipping" shape had already been rasterized, I would have to start from the beginning since it would look like this…

[image: http://i.imgur.com/OTwFgcH.png]

Thanks for reading this far.

Comment: Why would you need the person's head shape as part of the background circle shape? It seems a simple matter to have the background shape masked, then the person with a different mask. Are you trying to do everything with only 1 mask?

Comment: @Scott I'm not looking for one method in particular, just one that is less contrived but also non-destructive. Which, in my mind, means editable with less steps; Not necessarily less layers. If you have such a method, by all means, post an answer that illustrates your point.

Comment: @Scott My last paragraph actually illustrates the crux of my problem perfectly: Is there straightforward way to allowing my Person to "escape" my clipping mask and move around freely without Steps #2 through #6 [...] If I decided I wanted to offset my Person, after my "clipping" shape had already been rasterized, I would have to start from the beginning since it would look like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LlnsK.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be slightly simpler with Layer mask, but I prefer using Clipping mask if the edge of two layers meet.

> Some clarifications to the paragraph above.. I edited this in later because I was reading this question again after a long time and it took me a second to get what I was saying.
>
> What I meant here is that if we take this exact situation, the end result is going to have the bottom of the person layer meeting the edge of the circle layer at the bottom. Because you have 2 layers stacked up and because of anti-aliasing, if you use a `Layer mask` on the person layer, its edge is going to pass through some of the circle layer color. If you use a clipping mask, this won't happen. Long ago I made this image to explain this a bit more [Check it out here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROEca.png).

**Key points of the example images below:**

- The `person layer` is put into `Smart object` and duplicated.

  - This way you can just edit the smart object contents once and both images update.
- The first `person layer` is put in a `Clipping mask` with the circle.
- The second `person layer` has it's own `Layer mask` that masks out everything starting from the eyes.

  - Essentially the goal is to mask out the shoulders that would otherwise stick out, in this case anyways.
- Both `person layers` are linked, so that they are easy to move, rotate and resize.

**Example images below:**

<sub>Every layer showing</sub>

[image]

<sub>Second person layer hidden</sub>

[image]

<sub>Every layer except the second person layer hidden</sub>

[image]

---

<sup>I cut out a part of the circle, cause my person over here had his torso cut too short.</sup>

Comment: Thanks Joonas, this is WAY simpler and more manageable than the method I was using. Hey @scott is this close to the method you had mentioned?