# How to define custom shape cut-out with reference to other layers in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I saw the following graphic on a website, which I thought was quite a nice way of displaying an app, however, I am struggling to get the effect with the phone displaying on top of the circle, but using the bottom edge of the circle as a clipping path. How would I achieve this?

[image: Example]

Comment: You would have 2 copies of the phone, 1 with a clipping mask of the circle and one with no clipping mask that is above the circle.

Comment: Yea. What @AndrewH is suggesting will leave a better quality edge at all times. Here's how you could do that: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/38765/2332

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way without duplicating the phone layer:

1. select the phone layer
2. subtract the circle layer from the phone layer selection via
   <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+click (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+click mac) on the circle layer in the layer panel
3. deselect the top part of the phone you want to be visible
4. invert the selection
5. create a layer mask on the phone layer
   [image: layer mask process]

Comment: If I select all of the phone layer using `cmd click`, then hold down `cmd shift` then I just add the circle layer to my phone layer, how do I make this subtract?

Comment: It's `cmd+alt`, sorry I got that wrong. Edited my answer.

Comment: [Here's an explanation why the above method might not be a good idea in this case](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MTOnT.png). ( In the example image given by the OP, the blue circle edge would show through the edge of the smart phone screen. )