# How do you a get graphic both in front of and behind text like this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, print-design, text, print-production

[image]

I hope someone can help me. I know about Object, Arrange and text wrap and all that, but I still cannot figure out how to get an object to go both in front of and behind text at the same time as in this Take Heart logo. Working in InDesign or Illustrator. Can anyone help?

Comment: My guess is that the Heart shape is behind the text, but the text is masked off where the heart loops around front over the "e" and "H".

Comment: I suggest you read [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62707/how-to-overlap-custom-art-brush-shapes/65639#65639)

Answer (score 9):

Although it looks like a one-piece symbol, the heart icon is most likely made up of 2 shapes. Part of it will float over and part under the actual wording.

Comment: This is how I have done it in the past, in Photoshop however... I assume it would be similar. Place the Heart above and below the text in exactly the same spot. Then erase from the top heart everything to the right of the right most peak. Then the left half is still above the text. On the right half it appears the text is still above the heart, but you have just erased the heart on top and made the layer below visible. From there you can also select the two heart layers together to move them around if you want a different look.

Comment: Reminded me of this answer of mine https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/38765/2332 — It may just be confusing as it is in photoshop and only the core concept is the same, but just in case...

Answer (score 2):

- Placing the heart drawing behind the text, **Copy** it
- Select the text
- Make **Transparency Mask**
- Uncheck **Clip**
- Click the mask window and paste in front: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Win
- Stroke it with 100% black
- Use the **Direct Selection Tool** to select and delete the point over the heart *e*

  - If it's necessary use the Pen Tool to add a middle point
- Click the editing window

[image]